# Modifier of the verb try

Tags: modifiers

I have this quiz:

> __ he tried to cover up the truth, it came out at last.
>
> A. No matter what
>
> B. Whatever
>
> C. No matter how
>
> D. However hard

The given answer is `D` but I think all the four are right.

My reason is that the following sentences both make sense to me:

- He tried everything to conceal the truth. => `what`
- He tried very hard to conceal the truth. => `how`

Comment: You're correct that all four answers fit here.. But while we *cover objects* we *cover up* or *conceal* what we do not wish to become public knowledge.

Comment: All four *are* correct without further information. I can only assume there is some context around the quiz that has not been given.

Answer (score 1):

> - (A) No matter what he tried to cover up the truth, it came out at last.
> - (B) Whatever he tried to cover up the truth, it came out at last.
> - (C) No matter how he tried to cover up the truth, it came out at last.
> - (D) However hard he tried to cover up the truth, it came out at last.

Each of these four sentences is grammatically valid. Each is reasonably natural. I see no good reason within the question as given to prefer any one of the four, except possibly personal taste. Perhaps there was some context in the original quiz that made one of these preferable. Perhaps the question was poorly written, it seems that a significant number of ESL quizzes and tests are poorly written.

In any case, I cannot advise how to pass a particular quiz, but I can confidently assert that all four are grammatically valid.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speaker, so my answer is just an FYI.

I think **A**, **C** and **D** can fit, but **D** is most likely the intended answer, based upon the following reasons:

1. You need a conjunction to connect two independent clause, so **B** (whatever) is not fit.
2. All **A**, **C** and **D** can fit for the sentence grammatically. But semantically, **D** is the intended answer:

   *No matter what he tried to cover the truth* **means** *though he tried a lot of things to cover the truth*.

   *No matter how he tried to cover the truth* **means** *though he tried to cover the truth in many ways*.

   *However hard he tried to cover the truth* **means** *no matter how hard he tried to cover the truth*.

Comment: But I think `whatever` is a conjunction too: Whatever you do, slow down and take your time.

Comment: @尤慕李, yeah, you may be correct. Interestingly, some dictionaries say it can be a conjunction. The one I originally looked up doesn't have it.